# How to add a Checkbox beside each row in table

Tags: php, html, checkbox

How to make so a checkbox is added beside each row in a dynamic table? So if i get 5 result from databse i want to display 5 checkbox next to these results.

```
       <table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th>title</th>
    </tr>

        <?php

include 'database.php';

$valid_query = "SELECT * FROM agencies ";
$valid_result = mysqli_query($link, $valid_query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($valid_result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['title'].'</td>';
    <input type = 'checkbox' name = '$row[title]'>
    echo '<tr>';
}

        ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: *"How to"* - Stack isn't a "how to (build/write code for you)" site; have you tried anything first? And if so, what what difficulty did you have?

Comment: *Try* writing some code *1st*, and *learn*. 
If after [**researching this**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) and experienced some difficulties, post what you tried 
along with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** & provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. 
[Take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [**this**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937), then edit your question respectively; we'll be glad to take a **L@@K** at it. :-)

Comment: Yes i did try to add this code:  <input type = 'checkbox' name = '$row[title]'>  inside while loop but i got errors.

Comment: edit your question then https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44527340/edit it will help to see exactly where you tried to use it and what errors you received which should also be in the question.

Comment: you should be getting parse errors here with php's error reporting. You need to place the `<input type = 'checkbox' name = '$row[title]'>` inside an echo statement, encapsulated in quotes.

Comment: i did but i am getting synatx error

Comment: It's OK now i did it.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you resolved it yourself :-) *Cheers*

Comment: Btw; you have the option of posting your own answer and accepting it once the time allows you. I'll be glad to upvote it.